# changing from Http to Https for a website hosted in Azure

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I want my users clients from accessing the application from http  to https. Which i found that we should supply an SSl certificate in my Azure portal. But im still banging my head how do we get the certificate. i have a few Questions
1) Is it anything that we should run some commands and get the certificate as said here
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/
one of my friend said that it doesnt work we simply had to buy a certificate from a vendor and supply it to Azure
2) if not Is it free or we should buy.
3) if its not free which one should i Buy

Answer (score 1):

It does take a couple of commands (depending on the type of server you are using) to setup HTTPS. The link you provided shows a link where to obtain an SSL certificate (there's a link to a list of Certificate Authorities). Certificate Authorities (or CA) are those who provide SSL Certificates. There are a number of them and offer different levels of trust, as well as price.